# Where to place Resources

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application, I define a `Style` in my `App.xaml` and use it on other pages. But I want to compile my project into a .dll which requires me to delete `App.xaml`. So I need to place my `Style` somewhere else (preferably in a global place, not in every page that I make). Where can I put it and how can I use it?

I'm using MvvmCross by the way, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: put it in a xaml in a global place?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm asking how to do

Comment: No, the solution of that post suggests to put it in `App.xaml` which does not work in my situation.

Comment: sorry my bad, how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907874/wpf-basics-shared-global-styles-for-mvvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you create a new xaml anywhere you feel appropriate that contains `<ResourceDictionary>` and then you can load these Resource dictionaries where ever you want like:

```
 <Page.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary2.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

For global declarations, if you see the generated cs file for App.Xaml, you will see something like windowsForm's Program.cs file (Mixed with a Form partial class Codes).

here is a Part of this file: (App.i.g.cs)

```
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;

        #line 7 "..\..\App.xaml"
        this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        #line default
        #line hidden
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/WpfPlayground;component/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        #line 1 "..\..\App.xaml"
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

        #line default
        #line hidden
    }
```

Actually below line will forces the application to use your specific resouceDictionary file as a Global ResourceDictionary.

```
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
```

If you create a file that conforms App.xaml file (As you know this is the Main Entry-point of your EXE file), there will be no need to be depend on this file.

**Note:** App.i.g.cs is a AutoGenerated and you must conform the App.XAML rules.